# How to Handle Internet Connection when Requesting Data to RestAPI Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, internet-connection

I have `asynctask` for requesting JSON file from RestAPI, the problem is before webservice send JSON data, my connection have been lost, and get error because of that. I already have `ConnectivityManager` to check if connection establish i can run the `asynctask` for requesting JSON. How to handle when `asynctask` is already running?

This is my `ConnectivityManager` function:

```
public bool isOnline()
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo activeConnection = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            return activeConnection != null && activeConnection.IsConnected;

        }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin to build Android App.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which rest api client are you using?

Comment: What errors are you getting? and please provide code to request for JSON

Comment: are you getting timeout exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

/**
 * Net Utils for android
 */
public class NetUtils { 

    /**
     * @param context the context you're checking connectivity for
     * @return true if the application can access the internet
     */
    public static boolean hasConnectivity(Context context, boolean roamingOK) {
        boolean hasConnectivity = true;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        hasConnectivity = info != null && (info.isConnected() || (roamingOK && info.isRoaming()));
        return hasConnectivity;
    }

}
```

also add permission on manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```